# Trying to generate tables from Doctrine models and getting MySQL errors

Tags: mysql, model, doctrine, mysql-error-1146, mysql-error-1025

Doctrine_Core::createTablesFromModels() is failing with the following error:

1. `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'newmexicocreates.address_type' doesn't exist. Failing Query: "SELECT a.id AS a__id, a.title AS a__title FROM address_type a"' in /[removed]/lib/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php:1082`
2. `Stack trace:`
3. `#0 /[removed]/lib/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php(1025): Doctrine_Connection->rethrowException(Object(PDOException), Object(Doctrine_Connection_Mysql), 'SELECT a.id...')`
4. `#1 /[removed]/lib/doctrine/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(976): Doctrine_Connection->execute('SELECT a.id...', Array)`
5. `#2 /[removed]/lib/doctrine/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(1026): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->_execute(Array)`
6. `#3 /[removed]/app/models/behaviors/IdAsConstant.php(16): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->execute()`
7. `#4 /[removed]/ in /[removed]/lib/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1082`

I think this is happening because it's seeing relationships defined in the models and trying to create constraints. But the tables they're dealing with haven't been created yet. Am I correct in this assumption?

Is there anything I can try to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I traced this error to its source, I realized that the culprit was a behavior template that wasn't being "considerate".

Specifically, the behavior was assuming that the table existed while executing its setUp method.